# jQuery Sequentially Execute Async Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to code some JavaScript with jQuery that executes some asynchronous events sequentially (in a loop); only iterating afte the previous async event has completed.

The basic idea is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someLength; i++) {
    // 1. dynamically add a <form> and <input>s to the DOM
    // 2. submit the form to a target <iframe>
    // 3. wait for an async callback indicating the form has been submitted
}
```

I have working code for #1 and #2, and I can attach a `load` event  listener to the `<iframe>` to know when the form submit has completed:

```
$('.iframe').on('load', function() { ...
});

for (var i = 0; i < someLength; i++) {
    // 1. dynamically add a <form> and <input>s in the DOM
    // 2. submit the form to a target <iframe>
    // 3. wait for an async callback indicating the form has been submitted
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to tie the `ready` callback to the loop logic. I tried to look into deferreds/promises, but didn't really see how to correctly apply those concepts here.

If the answer is to use promises, then I would love to also see how to incorporate some code to show a "loading" spinner while the loop is going, and then remove the spinner once we're out of the loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`For-loop` dislike asynchronous operations especially if you want to *chain* them. A solution may look like this.

```
$('.iframe').on('load', function() { ...
    // increment i
    //if(i >= someLength) exit
    // 1. dynamically add a <form> and <input>s in the DOM
    // 2. submit the form to a target <iframe>
});

//for (var i = 0; i < someLength; i++) {//no loop
//}
    // 1. dynamically add a <form> and <input>s in the DOM
    // 2. submit the form to a target <iframe>
    // 3. nothing to wait
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex. So in this solution am I essentially queuing up all of the submits and then waiting for the `load` callback to fire `someLength` number of times? What if I only want to do the next submit if the previous one succeeded (assuming I have a way to know if it succeeded or failed)?

Comment: In the `.load` handler you can check current state and decide what to do next.

Comment: Right, but I think in your code all of the submit requests will get kicked off / queued in the `for` loop, and the `load` handler will just get called back when one request finishes. With this scheme, you can't prevent the next submit from executing if the previous one failed, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I can. Next submit comes from `.load` handler IIF the previous is success.

Comment: Oh oops.. didn't realize that you've commented out the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it in recursive way instead of a for loop. something like this-

```
$("#imgSpinner").show();
someFunction(0,someLength);

function someFunction(currentSeq,totalIterations)
{
    $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                     if (currentSeq<totalIterations)
                       someFunction(currentSeq++,totalIterations);
                     else
                       $("#imgSpinner").hide();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                //handle error

            }
     });

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not able to use `$.ajax` because I'm POSTing to a different domain. Ideally I would like a solution that still implements promises/deferreds since I want to learn (by example) how to properly use them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand how you can have a for-loop creating forms and fields... are all your forms containing the same fields? Ie multiple email addresses or something?

Without understanding the design, I'll give you this as an example of submitting some data then when that finishes submitting the next data.

```
$.when(AjaxSubmitFirstData.call()).done(function (data) {
  $.when(AjaxSubmitSecondData.call()).done(function (data) {
    // finished
  });
});

var AjaxSubmitFirstData = {
  call: function () {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: "{}",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }).done(function (data) {
    }).fail(function (jq, textStatus) {
    });
  }
};

var AjaxSubmitSecondData = {
  call: function () {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: "{}",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    }).done(function (data) {
    }).fail(function (jq, textStatus) {
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I need to create multiple forms is because I'm sending multiple a POSTs to a different domain (with different data in each request), and therefore cannot use AJAX (because of same origin policy). Are you able to modify your answer to show how to use deferreds when not using `$.ajax`?